# Azure classic cloud service configuration local vs cloud

Tags: azure, http, https, cloud, local

Problem #1:  I have a classic cloud service running a single web site role.  I would like to differentiate between the way it is debugged locally versus how it is deployed to the cloud.  Specifically I would like the local site to run on HTTP and the cloud service to run on HTTPS.  The main reason for this is that we don't want to have to install the same cert on all the developers' machines.  However, the endpoints are defined in the common "ServiceDefinition.csdef", NOT in the two "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" files ("local" and "cloud").  So, how do I set up different endpoints for local versus cloud?

Problem #2:  I would like, especially in the cloud, to have a site running on HTTP that simply redirects the user to the HTTPS site.  How would I set that up?

I realize these questions may not have sufficient detail, but I didn't want to write a book.  Please feel free to ask for clarification.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer to your questions:

> Problem #2: I would like, especially in the cloud, to have a site
>   running on HTTP that simply redirects the user to the HTTPS site. How
>   would I set that up?

For this, you can simply rely on web.config transforms. In your web.release.config you can set a redirection rule which will redirect http requests to https. Something like the following:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Similar thing would just not be present in your web.debug.config (or web.config).

> Specifically I would like the local site to run on HTTP and the cloud
>   service to run on HTTPS.

For this, the way I have handled it in the past when I worked on Cloud Services is basically I created separate cloud projects for each environment (WebApp.Azure.Dev, WebApp.Azure.Prod etc.). This way I would get separate csdef file for each environment.

Comment: Yep, this did the trick.  Using this I was able to get both local and cloud working like a charm.  Thanks a lot for your help!